# break the loop in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor

I have following setup code

```
var ele = element(by.model(xpath));
var option = ele.isDisplayed().then(function(found) {
    ele.all(by.tagName('option')).then(function(options) {
        options.some(function(option) {
            option.getText().then(function doesOptionMatch(text) {
                if (text == data.trim()) {
                    logger.debug("PASS--" + data.trim() + "--option selected");
                    return "PASS"; //not working
                }
                if (text != data.trim())
                    logger.debug("FAIL--" + data.trim() + "--option is Not selected");
            });

        });
    });
}, function(err) {
    logger.debug("FAIL--Exception caught in verifyDropdownSelectedValue--" + err);
});
```

and I want the control to be out of the loop where the return statement is written but it is not working and continuing the iteration. Here is the looping part that is not exiting when I return a truthy value

```
 options.some(function(option) {
     option.getText().then(function doesOptionMatch(text) {
         if (text == data.trim()) {
             logger.debug("PASS--" + data.trim() + "--option selected");
             return "PASS"; //not working
         }
         if (text != data.trim())
             logger.debug("FAIL--" + data.trim() + "--option is Not selected");
     });
 });
```

Comment: Define "not working"; what specifically are you expecting? The `return` statement will return from the inner-most function, which are nested four deep. Also it's a little hard to see what's going on in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) on `Array.some()`, it exits the loop if the callback function returns true

> some() executes the callback function once for each element present in
>   the array until it finds one where callback returns a truthy value (a
>   value that becomes true when converted to a Boolean). If such an
>   element is found, some() immediately returns true. Otherwise, some()
>   returns false

Your `some - callback function` doesnt not return true, infact it doesnt return anything. Even the `return "PASS"` value is for function `doesOptionMatch` and not for `function(option)` which is callback for `some()`

I changed the Code to something like below which iterates through `getText()` values Array and return true when there is a match. Its working as expected

```
var ele = element(by.tagName('select'));
var option = ele.isDisplayed().then(function(found) {
    ele.all(by.tagName('option')).getText().then(function(textValues) {
        textValues.some(function(textValue) {
            if (textValue == data.trim()) {
                logger.debug("PASS--" + data.trim() + "--option selected");
                return true;
            }
            if (textValue != data.trim())
                logger.debug("FAIL--" + data.trim() + "--option is Not selected");
        })
    })
});
```

Comment: one more help needed if i write like this var allElements=[];var option = ele.isDisplayed().then(function(found) {
   ele.all(by.tagName('option')).getText().then(function(textValues) {
    textValues.some(function(textValue) {
     allElements.push(textValue);

    });
   });
   
   console.log("Array Length--"+allElements.length);
  }); it returns the size of array allElements as 0,How can i get all the elements of list added in the array allElements outside of the promise?